# Hibernate NamedNativeQuery with PostgreSQL returns 'relation does not exist'

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I created a bean class to fit an entry on list in my webapp, because this bean should use data from many db tables I decided to use `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation, so I can fetch excactly the data is needed (for decrease list loading time).
When I call:

```
getSession().createCriteria(ProjectListEntry.class).list();
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: relation "projectlistentry" does not exist
Position: 29
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1897)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1698)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:832)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2382)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2368)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2198)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2193)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:122)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1622)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.__xr__list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.__xr__uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:396)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java)
...
```

Of course I don't have projectlistentry table in my database, because I want to create this entity from the query.

My `ProjectListEntity` class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "compositeKey",
    entities = @EntityResult(
            entityClass = <path>.ProjectListEntry.class,
            fields = {
                    @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "p_id"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "title", column = "p_title"),
                    ...
            }
    ))
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "fetchProjectListEntry",
    query = "SELECT p.id AS p_id, " +
                "p.title AS p_title, " +
                ... many fields and many joins here ...,
    resultSetMapping = "compositeKey")
public class ProjectListEntry {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    ...
}
```

Query in the `query` parameter when copied to pgadmin is working correctly, showing a list of all data I want to put in this class instances.

I must use this class with Criteria API, so

```
getSession().createCriteria(ProjectListEntry.class).list();
```

must work properly, giving me list of results exactly the same as query in pgadmin.

I am also open to suggestions which, would lead me to solve this problem even not using `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation. If there is a need i can provide some more informations.

Comment: Please show the definition of the table (the `create table` statement). My guess is, you created the table using double quotes which makes the name case-sensitive:  `"projectlistentry"` is a different name than `"ProjectListEntry"`. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I wrote there is no such table in my database. I want to construct this entity using data from various tables, and that's why I'm trying to use `@NamedNativeQuery`, but still I must do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create view in database with your query and then map it to your entity.

This solution is not perfect because if you want to change your bean you must change view too.

This method is not using `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation but probably will work.